# amchart changebullet on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

Im trying to change the image of the bullet Im clicking on (in amchart)
and it does not effect any.

Im trying to have an eventlistner, and change the property of the item in a function. but it doesnt have any effect on the ui somehow

anyone have an idea why ?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        Try();

    });

    function Randomize() {

        return Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    }

    function Try() {

        var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
            "type": "serial",
            "theme": "none",
            "pathToImages": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/",
            "dataProvider":

                buildMe()

            ,

            "balloon": {
                "cornerRadius": 6
            },
            "valueAxes": [{
                "duration": "mm",
                "durationUnits": {
                    "hh": "h ",
                    "mm": "min"
                },
                "axisAlpha": 0
            }],
            "graphs": [{
                "bullet": "square",
                "bulletSize": 14,
                "customBullet": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/star.png",
                "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
                "bulletBorderThickness": 1,
                "fillAlphas": 0.3,
                "fillColorsField": "lineColor",
                "legendValueText": "[[value]]",
                "lineColorField": "lineColor",
                "customBulletField": "customBullet",
                "title": "duration",
                "valueField": "duration"
            }],
            "chartScrollbar": {},
            "chartCursor": {
                "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "YYYY MMM DD",
                "cursorAlpha": 0,
                "zoomable": false
            },
            "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
            "categoryField": "date",
            "categoryAxis": {
                "dateFormats": [{
                    "period": "DD",
                    "format": "DD"
                }, {
                    "period": "WW",
                    "format": "MMM DD"
                }, {
                    "period": "MM",
                    "format": "MMM"
                }, {
                    "period": "YYYY",
                    "format": "YYYY"
                }],
                "parseDates": true,
                "autoGridCount": false,
                "axisColor": "#555555",
                "gridAlpha": 0,
                "gridCount": 50
            }
        });
         var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
        chart.addListener("clickGraphItem", ChangePan,$(this));

    }


    function ChangePan(event) {
        event.item.dataContext.customBullet = "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/redstar.png";
        event.item.lineColor = "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/redstar.png";
         console.log(event.item.dataContext.customBullet);
        console.log(event.item);
    }

    function buildMe() {
        console.log('im in ?')
        var mystring = "";
        var year = 0;
        var month = 0;
        var session = 6;
        var training = 7;

        mystring += "[";
        for (var j = 0; j < training + 1; j++) {

            mystring += '{';


            if (Randomize() < 7) {
                mystring += '"lineColor": "#2498d2",';
            }
            else {
                mystring += '"lineColor": "#1153e6",';
            }
            mystring += ' "date": "2015-07-'+ j +'", "duration": ';

            mystring += Randomize();

           // mystring += ',"customBullet": "http://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/images/redstar.png"';

            if (training == j) {
                mystring += "}";
            }
            else {
                mystring += "},";
            }


        }
        mystring += "]";
        console.log(mystring)
        console.log(JSON.parse(mystring))
        return JSON.parse(mystring);
    }
```

this is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q70nLgpo/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AmCharts won't listen to dataContext changes, so you have to do it on your own using `validateData()`.
However, as the chart is completly redrawn, the point will lose its hover state.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmfme095/)